# Não consigo acessar propriedade em query SQL no Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js

Estou tentando criar um código que faz login em um site, porém quando ele pega os dados do banco para fazer uma verificação, recebo um erro.

Meu código atual:

```
router.post('/loginClin', function(req, res, next) {
  var query = "SELECT * FROM bdlabella.tbclientes WHERE email_cli = ?",
    /// ;            será preenchido pelo mysql com o valor informado ^ 
        where = [ req.body.email_login ];
    /// ;                  ^ valor informado

    conn.query( query, where, (err, results) => {


    console.log('bd: '+results.email_cli); // nesse memento no cmd aparece bd: undefined
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        if( results && results.length > 0 ){  
            if(results.email_cli == req.body.email_login && results.senha_cli == req.body.senha_login){
              loginClin.render(1 ,req, res, null, null);
              console.log("entrou");
            } else{
            loginClin.render(2, req, res, 'Email ou senha Incorretos1', null, results);
            console.log("Email ou senha Incorretos1");
          }
        }
        else{
          loginClin.render(2, req, res, 'Email ou senha Incorretos2', null);
          console.log("Email ou senha Incorretos2");
        }
    });
});
```

A seguinte linha:

```
console.log('bd: ' + results.email_cli)
```

Produz o output:

> ```
> bd: undefined
> ```

Comment: Qual o resultado de `console.log(results)` no console?

Comment: console.log('bd: '+results.email_cli); // nesse memento no cmd aparece bd: undefined

Comment: console.log('bd: '+results); // nesse memento no cmd aparece bd: [objets objets ]   algo assim

Comment: Não use `console.log('bd: '+results)`. Use somente `console.log(results)` e edite a sua resposta, adicionando o valor retornado. Se você tentar concatenar em uma `string`, não conseguirá demonstrar direito.

Comment: [ TextRow {
    cod_cli: 2,
    nome_cli: 'Samuel Melo da ',
    sob_cli: 'Silva',
    telefone_cli: '997356115',
    email_cli: 'samuel.ms2112@gmail.com',
    senha_cli: '123',
    ativo: 1 } ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a sua query não está retornando um objeto único, mas sim uma lista de objetos. No seu caso, o retorno é exatamente esse:

```
[
  TextRow {
    cod_cli: 2,
    email_cli: 'Algum Valor',

    // Demais propriedades...
  }
]
```

Desse modo, para acessar **primeiro objeto retornado**, você deve fazer:

```
results[0].email_cli
```

Se você quiser, no entanto, percorrer sobre cada propriedade retornada, você deverá utilizar um laço `for`. Algo como:

```js
for (const row of result) {
    console.log(row.email_cli)
}
```

Comment: vlw mano ajudou de mais